# How to get an inverse fourier transform of a experimental frequency domain signal?

Tags: matlab, fft, ifft

I just use digital processing signal punctually and right know I need a just simple thing.

I have an IFR in time domain that magnitude and phase are known and the angular frequency as well.
I mean, I just know:

```
w = w0:dw:wf;
H(jw) = modH.*exp(j.*argH)
```

Applying the inverse Fourier transform, I get the IRF in time domain h(t) that I know that is non-causal.
How can I obtain `h(t)` in MATLAB with a correct time axis?

In advanced, I appreciate any help!

Comment: You can either shift the result in time, or use the identity concerning FT of time-shifted data (basically a spiral in complex space).

Comment: Often people forget to shift the signal prior to taking the inverse DFT. Perhaps something like `ifft(ifftshift(... ))` is what's wrong. Without more details from you I cannot offer any more help.

Comment: @BenVoigt, the curious thing here it is that the result from the ifft it's a complex number. At least for me, it's a surprise, once in time domain the values are not complex.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85, there is no more details, because I just apply: h(t)=ifft(H(jw)). But, as i said above, curious the complex result.

Comment: @Hugo: A causal signal will have a complex FFT.  As long as it is symmetric, when you do IFFT, the time domain signal will be pure real.